# JavaFX handler don't work

Tags: java, javafx

I have problem with controller. When I click on the button, nothing happens.
The method, which will be work:

```
@FXML
    public void handleNewProject() {
        code.setText("");
        inOutPut.setText("");
    }
```

It's button:

```
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleNewProject" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="New" />
```

**MainApp**

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("MyLittleIDE");

    initRootLayout();

    showDesk();
    showTool();
}

public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showDesk() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/DeskLayout.fxml"));
        AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showTool() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/ToolLayout.fxml"));
        GridPane tool = (GridPane) loader.load();

        rootLayout.setBottom(tool);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

...
```

}

**ToolLayout**

```
public class ToolLayoutController {
    @FXML
    private TextArea code;
    @FXML
    private TextArea inOutPut;

    @FXML
    public void handleNewProject() {
        code.setText("");
        inOutPut.setText("");
    }
}
```

fxml's:

**ToolLayout**

```
<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ru.mrchebik.view.ToolLayoutController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleNewProject" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="New" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Compile" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Run" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Save" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**DeskLayout**

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ru.mrchebik.view.ToolLayoutController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.8015075376884422" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="87.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
               <children>
                  <TextArea fx:id="code" layoutX="39.0" layoutY="-27.0" prefHeight="315.0" prefWidth="598.0" promptText="Code" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
               <children>
                  <TextArea fx:id="inOutPut" layoutX="-21.0" layoutY="-73.0" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="598.0" promptText="Input/Output" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and RootLayout have simple MenuBar, without settings

Comment: Don't you get a `NullPointerException`? ToolLayout, which has the button that invokes `handleNewProject()`, doesn't have any controls with `fx:id ="code"` or `fx:id ="inOutPut"`. So in the controller for ToolLayout, those fields should be null.

Comment: No, I don't get any exceptions.

It is not dependent, wich id I will be choose. I tried the System.out.println or add id for this button and when you press the button, change the text.

Comment: And how I can add any controls with id 'code' and 'inOutPut'?

Comment: Try by replacing `onMouseClicked` with `onAction`

Comment: And to answer the comment, in your ToolLayout.fxml, when you add controls, you specify them with the attribute `fx:id="ID"` where ID should be for example `"code"`. That's how you reference controls of a FXML in its controller

Comment: You are using the same class for two of your controllers (one for ToolLayout and one for DeskLayout). Start by using a different class for the controllers for each FXML file.

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same effect...